# Oauth2 is rejecting the request for login page how do I fix

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I've enabled OAuth2 in my Spring IO [2.0.6 Platform](http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) as follows

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure( final HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/**" )
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

}
```

but when I go to `/` for my `index.html` which has my login form I receive the following.

```
<oauth>
<error_description>
Full authentication is required to access this resource
</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

here's what appears to be relevant debug level logsj

```
2016-07-20 17:34:50.063 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@174f5835
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/css/**']
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/css/**'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/js/**']
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/js/**'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/images/**']
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/images/**'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error']
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/error'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/oauth/token'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key']
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/oauth/token_key'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/oauth/check_token'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@6c710c23
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in headers. Trying request parameters.
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in request parameters.  Not an OAuth2 request.
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : No token in request, will continue chain.
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Requested session ID B18ACABBAAF00852E3373A4EB0BDDCE2 is invalid.
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.064 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.065 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [#oauth2.throwOnError(authenticated)]
2016-07-20 17:34:50.065 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-07-20 17:34:50.066 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@1a3d182d, returned: -1
2016-07-20 17:34:50.066 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.066 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'authorizationAuditListener'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.067 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.067 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'auditListener'
2016-07-20 17:34:50.067 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Wed Jul 20 17:34:50 CDT 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
2016-07-20 17:34:50.068 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) [spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]

2016-07-20 17:34:50.068 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2016-07-20 17:34:50.072 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.o.p.e.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer : Written [error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"] as "application/xhtml+xml" using [org.springframework.security.oauth2.http.converter.jaxb.JaxbOAuth2ExceptionMessageConverter@c4b9155]
2016-07-20 17:34:50.072 DEBUG 15064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

What do I need to do to allow requests through to my `/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I have to do the following, `/` and `/index.html` are both required, the rest depends on your layout, though I did have to define allowing the `/webjars/` which is surprising

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure( final WebSecurity web ) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers( "/", "/index.html", "/partials/**/*.html" )
                .antMatchers( "/webjars/**/*.js" )
                .antMatchers( "/webjars/**/*.css" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure( final HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        super.configure( http );
    }

}
```